# How to show the layout used in the koma script documentation?

Tags: koma-script

I'm aware of the `layout` package, though how can I display the layout similar as here (koma script documentation)?:
[image: Text]

Comment: AFAIK this is an included picture in the documentation, originally  drawn using metapost.

Comment: Maybe you only need `showframe` package?

Comment: If your layout is as specialized as this one, you will have to draw it yourself. No package could possibly know which elements and dimensions it should consider.